# How to set www subdomain in my aws route53 domain?? (I tried many ways, but not worked)

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have domain in aws route53 (xxxxx.xxx), and I tried to alias "www" subdomain
with "create record set". I tried, alias, cname, ns, A,,, but it was no use.
(I have EC2 instance to connect, I connected to "xxxxx.xxx" domain successfully,
but I want to use "www.xxxxx.xxx".

Pls anybody can advise how to make it available "www.xxxxx.xxx" with my domain "xxxxx.xxx"? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/) ? There's also [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html)

Comment: yeah. I tried both of them. Thank!